# react js onMouseEnter change image

Tags: reactjs

lets say that i have a function that returns:

```
 return (
            <div>
              <ul>
                <div><img className='privewimg' src={user.img1}/></div>
                <div><img className='privewimg' src={user.img2}/></div>
                <div><img className='privewimg' src={user.img3}/></div>
              </ul>
            </div>
        );
```

now, i want to add the functions 
onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave

so every time that the mouse enter to some div, the image of the spesific div will change to some other picture (for example "xxx.png")

can anyone help me with this?

thanks,

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/76120/

Comment: @ReiDien thanks!
but how do i call the this.handleMouseEnter with parameter?
this.handleMouseEnter('img111.jpg') gave me an error..
thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/76171/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Component state to update image url.

```
changeImage = (img) => {
  this.setState({
    user: {
     [img]: newImageUrl
    }
  });
}

resetImage = (img) => {
  this.setState({
    // set the old image
  });
}

render() { 
  const { user } = this.state;

  return (
     <div>
       <ul>
         <li onMouseEnter={() => this.changeImage('img1')} onMouseLeave={() => this.resetImage('img1')}>
           <img className='privewimg' src={user.img1}/>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the state for the image source. And whenever the mouse hovers over the div, change the image source. Something like this:

```
handleMouseOver() {
   this.setState({imageSrc: 'dummySrc1'});
}

handleMouseLeave() {
   this.setState({imageSrc: 'dummySrc2'});
}

render() {
    return(
        <div onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>
             <img src={this.state.imageSrc}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

You can also use the redux store for the image path.